# How to determine my site's FCP?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been read about FCP from google insights. But still i don't know how i can determine my site's FCP and etc.

Can somebody inform me about this or share more detailed links about this  with me ?

Comment: Check out https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 'First Contentful Paint' / 'First Meaningful Plain', you can use lighthouse extension. In-fact it is built-in with Chrome under 'Audit' tab of Chrome DevTools.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#audits

Comment: thanks for reply. i know to get fcp timing. i don't know that how i determine it on design, which parts of site shown first and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could get it from `Network` panel in chrome devtool.
[image]